# VB.net create Active Directory account on another domain

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I have two Active Directory forests on separate domains. Call them Domain1 and Domain2.

I want to be able to run this application from a computer in Domain1 and it will create an account in Domain2. I know this can be done in PowerShell by using new-pssession. Any help is appreciated.

-M

Answer (score 0):

Excellent tutorial on all things .net -> AD.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19689/Working-with-Active-Directory-in-VB-NET

You'll need to make sure that you have access to LDAP/ADSI from where ever you run the application though. Being on another domain isn't the issue, not being inside the current network where the AD server resides is, usually these things aren't internet facing due to it being a massive security concern.